# Triggering non-interrupting boundary event with variables

Tags: bpmn, camunda

My question is about the Camunda API method `RuntimeService#messageEventReceived(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>)`. We use this method to trigger a non-interrupting boundary message event (on a receive task that is waiting for a different message), [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q41Bq.png). As third parameter in the method call, we are passing some process variables.

As expected, this leaves the receive task active and starts a new execution leaving the boundary event. I would have expected that the process variables passed to the third argument of `RuntimeService#messageEventReceived` would now be stored in the newly created execution, but it seems to be the case that they are stored in the execution of the receive task. This does not make much sense to me, because this is not the execution that "resulted" from the message.

We can workaround this problem by determining which execution is new after the execution of `RuntimeService#messageEventReceived` and attaching process variables there manually. But this does not seem very elegant - does anyone know a better solution? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Please post your process model. Also be aware that handling of executions is internal api concept and should not been used to determine your processing.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, see the java doc of the method
[void messageEventReceived(String, String, Map)](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.8/org/camunda/bpm/engine/RuntimeService.html#messageEventReceived(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map))

```
void messageEventReceived(String messageName,
                        String executionId,
                        Map<String,Object> processVariables)
Notifies the process engine that a message event with the name 'messageName' has been received and has been correlated to an execution with id 'executionId'. The waiting execution is notified synchronously. Note that you need to provide the exact execution that is waiting for the message if the process instance contains multiple executions.
Parameters:
messageName - the name of the message event
executionId - the id of the process instance or the execution to deliver the message to
processVariables - a map of variables added to the execution
```

Since the process variables are set on the existing execution they are also available on the new created child execution.

As alternative you could create a `ServiceTask` after the Boundary event, which creates the process variables **OR** you create another `ReceiveTask` after the Boundary event. This receive task could be completed with your message and the needed variables.